# iPad w/Retina Safari - reported dimensions in landscape make no sense

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, orientation, screen-resolution

I'm working on a webpage for Retina Display iPad and iPad Mini. Using window.innerWidth and .innerHeight, in Portrait it displays as 980x1185, but in Landscape it displays as 981x644.

WAT.

That makes no sense to me. Why is this happening??

Answer (score 0):

Safari is scaling the page to be the same width as it was in Portrait mode. What you're seeing is number of **points**, not **pixels**.

In order to prevent this behavior, you can tweak the `viewport` meta tag.

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
</head>
```

You can learn more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).